# Tomcat7/Jackson/WebApp deployment crash/

Tags: java, tomcat, jackson

I'm trying to deploy a new version of my web app on a Ubuntu server (12.04) running Tomcat 7.0.26.  Rather than include the jackson- libraries that I use (`-core`, `-annotations`, and `-databind`), I'm trying to place them in the `/usr/share/tomcat7/lib` area for use by other applications that I plan to deploy.

I can start the server, and deploy my app. However, once I do, the app crashes and takes down Tomcat. Clearly the ObjectMapper is not being properly loaded, but it exists in the databind jar file (I've jar tvf'd it to check)...

The response to the client is:

```
HTTP Status 500 -
type Exception report
message
description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

And, the catalina.out log file shows the following after the app is executed:

```
Mar 11, 2013 1:42:55 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 11, 2013 1:42:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Mar 11, 2013 1:42:57 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 11, 2013 1:42:57 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1587)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546)
    at org.comtor.authserv.APIServer.doPost(APIServer.java:150)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Mar 11, 2013 1:42:57 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
```

Any help here is appreciated. I'm attempting to learn what is going wrong, how I can prevent it, and also prevent the server from going down (crashing) when the web application is executed and this happens.

Thanks.

Comment: The fact that its crashing *only* when your app is deployed is suspicious. What libraries are bundled in your WAR? If you are using Maven to manage your app please add the POM to your question, otherwise list out the JAR's from the WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: There were no jars included in the lib folder. (Does an empty folder need to be present?)  Also, I am not using Maven. I have not had time to learn that (yet).

Comment: No JARs at all? So all your application's code is in the WEB-INF/classes folder? That doesn't sound likely for anything but the most trivial web app. Do you have any third party classes in WEB-INF/classes?

Comment: I was trying to place all third party jars into the TOMCAT lib for convenience, so that when I change the app, I don't need to create a big war file.  Also, some core underlying functionality of the overall application is in its own jar, also in the lib. Then, the webapp is just the code to create the web service which in turn makes calls to the 3rd party libs and my lib.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with the Jersey REST libraries. It turned out that Tomcat was crashing my app because there was a version conflict between some jars I included in my WAR file and jars I had moved to Tomcat's lib folder.

I recommend that you troubleshoot this on a local development machine first because it is quicker and easier to move jar files around. Start with just the libraries Tomcat comes with and all of your required libraries packed into your war file. Your app should run fine. Then move jar files from your app to Tomcat lib. You can do this without re-building your app. Just open your war file with an unzip utility like 7-zip and delete the files from your war file as you move them to Tomcat/lib. You probably need to restart Tomcat every time but I found it didn't take me long to get a working configuration this way.  Now my war file is only 735KB instead of 8MB, which matters to me because I'm working with a slow upload speed.

Comment: Update: I installed Tomcat7 on my mac and re-warred up the file with all the libs.  The result is exactly the same.

https://gist.github.com/depasqua/5131835

Comment: @docSquale - Looking at your gist, you still have the Jackson JARs bundled in your web app. You cannot have them in both locations (bundled inside the app, and also deployed in Tomcats library). Remove them from the WAR, redeploy and retest.

Comment: @docSquale If you just installed Tomcat on your Mac, then it shouldn't have the jackson libraries, so I'm surprised you have this error. Did you ever get your app to run? If so, under what environment was it running? Ubunu?

Comment: Tomcat was installed (as a test as you suggested above) on my local machine (Mac).  I didn't see the jackson libraries installed with Tomcat, and am not familiar with what else might be installed on the Mac. 

However, I seemed to have traced the problem down to the fact that my code (threaded) is having interrupted exceptions thrown and the threads are dying. The ObjectMapper loading comes after the thread use, and it looks like that is a residual side effect.  

This all worked fine before I got the bright idea to refactor the code and take some out into it's own library.

Comment: It looks like your issue is not the library placements, but other refactoring you may have done. Mac or Ubuntu shouldn't matter. I think the basic Tomcat installation comes with the same libraries regardless of which platform you place it on.